# Ruby-on-Rails Model Naming Covention Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, model

In a rails project I have named my Model "Alumni" but according to the rails convention the Model should be singular form while the table in the database should be of Plural form. But now that I have named the Model as Alumni, What would be the name of the table in the Database?
PS - I am using POSTGRESQL

Comment: Run db:migrate and find out? Check the inflections?

Comment: I would like to know now that I have named the database Alumni what would be the name of the database at present and the procedure to reset the name

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I recognize, 'alumni' is plural form of 'alumnus', but it's irregular, so I think the best you can do is:

a) Name your model `Alumnus`
b) Name your table `alumni`
c) Define irregular in inflector:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'alumnus', 'alumni'
end
```

But if you don't want to rebuild your data model and you want to stick with `Alumni` model name, you should name your table:

```
'alumni'.pluralize
# => "alumnis"
```

Comment: Thumbs up for using Inflector.

Comment: Yeah I agree to the fact that I have defaulted the convention but I have developed significantly without noticing this and now reverting back would take up a lot of time.
So could you please tell me what do without reverting back.
Also how to check the name of the table of Alumni Model?
One more query what is inflector and how to use it?

Comment: @user3656952 Set the table name for the model. Please see the Rails AR docs.

Comment: @MarekLipka - could you please explain about the inflector or redirect to any resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
Alunmi : Alumnus :: Plural : Singular
```

Model name must be `Alumnus` and table name must be `Alumni`. (untested for convention in Rails)

You can still use `Alumni` for both model and table and specify `set_table_name 'alumni'` in the model.

Edit: If your model name is `Alumni` and table name is also the same, then in `alumni.rb` file:

```
# Since you have not specified Rails version, then
## Rails 3.2+ and 4
class Alumni < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'alumni'
  # your other code
end

## Rails 3.1 and below
class Alumni < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'alumni'
  # your other code
end
```

HTH

Comment: won't work by default, `'alumnus'.pluralize` returns `'alumnus'`.

Comment: How can we set the name of the table, could you please tell me the procedure

Answer (score 0):

If you have called your model "Alumni", the name of the table in the database will be "alumnis":

```
rails c
> class Alumni < ActiveRecord::Base
> end
> Alumni.table_name
=> "alumnis"
```